# Como trabalhar com o autocomplete do jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estou usando [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) do jQuery, mas estou tendo o seguinte problema:

Na primeira linha do `<select>` gostaria que aparecesse o famoso `"Escolha abaixo uma opção"`

```
<option value="">Escolha abaixo uma opção</option>
```

Ou, no caso de edição, valor do `<select>` vindo do banco.

Mas nada que faço funciona, só aparece uma linha em branco.

Obs.: O autocoplete funciona normal. O `<select>` popula normal com os dados vindos do banco. O problema é só a primeira linha do `<select>`.

Criei o script abaixo que tecnicamente deveria preencher a primeira linha do `<select>`.

```
$stringClientes = "";

if($Clientes == null)   {
    $stringClientes .= "<option value=''>Ainda não existe Cliente cadastrado</option>";
}
else {
    $ClienteCadastro = $ClientesDao->pesquisaClienteEdicao($_GET["idClienteCadastro"]);

    if(isset($_GET["idClienteCadastro"]) && $ClienteCadastro != null) {     
        $stringClientes .= "<option value='".$ClienteCadastro->getIdClientes()."'>".$ClienteCadastro->getNome()."</option>";        
    } else {
        $stringClientes .= '<option value="">Escolha um cliente abaixo</option>';
    }
    
    foreach ($Clientes as $cliente) {
        $stringClientes .= "<option value='".$cliente->getIdClientes()."'>".$cliente->getNome()."</option>";
    }
}
```

E, no `<select>`

```
  <div>
        <label>Cliente</label>
        <select name="cliente" id="cliente" required>
            <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
             <?php echo $stringClientes; ?>
        </select><br /> <br /> 
  </div>
```

Em tempo. A variável, `$stringClientes`, traz corretamente ao `<select>` todos os `<option>`s, inclusive a primeira linha. Mas parece que o autocomplete não permite que coloquemos texto no combobox.

O retorno completo do select sai assim:

```
<select name="cliente" id="cliente" required>
    <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
    <option value='17'>José das couves</option>
    <option value='14'>Fulano de Tal</option>
    <option value='15'>tal fulano</option>
    <option value='16'>Antônio Bandeiras</option>
    <option value='17'>José das couves</option>
</select>
```

Mas a primeira linha: `<option value="" selected>Selecione</option>` não sai!

Nesse caso pensei em popular o `type['text']` com o valor `""` ou o que vem do banco. Como preencher esse `type['text']` que só esta no plugin?

Comment: Agora entendi! É que o autocomplete não aceitou value="". Coloquei value="#" e funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Com o exemplo do site, funciona perfeitamente e faz isso que você quer [Neste link](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

[Exemplo aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/z9mjpxcr/)

[image: Select]

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Exemplo completo do site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },

          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="toggle">Show underlying select</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não tem a frase: "Selecione uma opção abaixo" ou algo do gênero! O Select one... dele só funciona se clikar no botão para exibir o Select. E isso não gostaria de fazer. Por isso gostaria de preencher a caixa de texto dele

Comment: @CarlosRocha na pagina oficial realmente não tem, mas no código que postei ai tem sim, dê uma olhada no primeiro option      <option value="">Select one...</option>. Vou postar uma imagem ai.

Comment: Observe que no teu código existe o dbText( type['text']) esta vazia. Mas o select esta preenchido. Preciso preencher o dbText( type['text']), NÃO o select. O select já esta preenchido corretamente. Entende?

Comment: Estava pensando em alterar o valor desse campo por aqui: Algo do tipo: 
 $( "#nomeDoCampo" ).value(); Mas não sei como fazer pois não tenho o nome do campo!

Comment: Agora entendi! É que o autocomplete não aceitou value="". Coloquei value="#" e funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa definir um "**value**" para a opção "**Selecione**". Veja:http://jsfiddle.net/emirdeliz/swqwLfxu/

```
<select id="combobox">
    <option value="selecione">Select algo</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
```

Caso queira usar um valor em branco é só remover o "text" da option conforme abaixo:

```
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="selecione"></option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Sim, mas e no caso de edição de formulário, como alterar esse option para o option com o valor do banco? Meu select já esta assim. O problema é popular o type["text']. Você pode fazer um html e postar na tua reposta fazendol favor?

Comment: Veja o exemplo @CarlosRocha

Comment: Sim. mas se eu copiar e colar não funciona direito. parece falta alguma coisa entende? Já tive esse problema aqui e a pessoal me passou o html todo e então funcionou. Testei aqui mas só sai a selet option

Comment: Copie e cole: <option value="selecione"></option>

Comment: Ou copie daqui: http://jsfiddle.net/emirdeliz/swqwLfxu/

Comment: Agora entendi! É que o autocomplete não aceitou value="". Coloquei value="#" e funcionou!

Comment: Pode fechar o tópico ;)

Comment: Preciso de outra ajuda ainda aqui. onde nesse código, é feito o autocomplete letra por letra digitada? É que preciso fazer uma busca cada vez que o autocomplete completar até encontrar uma combinação com o select!

Comment: Essa rotina é do próprio plugin do Jquery. Se entendi a tua duvida, conforme o usuário for digitando, caso nenhum das opções atenderem o seu filtro, uma nova consulta deverá ser feita trazendo somente os registro que atendem o que o usuário digitou. Seria isso?

Comment: Mais ou menos. digitei a letra A, não existe combinação na select option, digitei a letra c, não existe combinação na select option, depois de algumas teclas, cheguei na formação 'Action Script', tem um opção ou na li criada dinamicamente ou em uma das opções do option, então, dispara o ajax. Disparar o ajax eu consigo, mas encontrar uma forma de fazer isso pelo keydown ta difícil.

Comment: Olha quer coisa estranha ocorre. Fiz:  ***this.input.on("keydown", function () { alert($("this.input").val()); });*** O ***keydown*** ocorre dentro do campo. mas o ***alert()*** diz que o campo é indefinido

Comment: Vixi, estou enrolado agora, a noite dou uma olhada OK?

Comment: ta bom. sem problemas. Bom trabalho e até a note!

Comment: Tenta dar um console.log no valor